# Android can't find any BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here's he problem. I've developed an app for iOS to control an BLE LED device (and a few other things). Everything works fine and smooth. Now I wanted develop the same app for android and I already fail at the scanning of BLE devices. I have tried a few tutorials and sample codes but whatever I do I can't find any devices. I work on a Moto G4 Play. The bluetooth works and I can pair devices in the settings but it won't work with any sample code/tutorial I've tried.
For example this one:
https://github.com/kaviles/BLE_Tutorials

I build this app as it is and it can't find anything.

So I downloaded a BLE Scanner from the Playstore and that works fine to and finds all devices.

I know it's hard to say without any sample code but I've tried so many and I'm not sure if I miss something completely basic.

Comment: Check the permissions of the application. Check the SDK 23 permissions because you need location permissions. Make sure location services are on. Other than that, check your code is fine!

Comment: I set all permissions but it won't work anyway. According to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196485
it seems to be quite an issue

Comment: This is not an issue, it is intended behaviour because BLE devices can give out location information. You must add the location services permissions, and if you are building against API 23+, you must ask for permissions in runtime.

Comment: I meant an issue for developers. Seems as there are a lot of complaints about this.

Comment: Are there any recommendations for libraries that take care of these issues?

Comment: The manifest permissions have to be set nonetheless by the application developer. About runtime permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you have to set up the permissions accordingly if your targetSdk is 23+ or other. The location services must be on.

Manifest permissions for API 23+:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

To check bluetooth permissions:

```
    public boolean hasBlePermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

To request runtime permissions with :

```
public void requestBlePermissions(final Activity activity, int requestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            requestCode);
}
```

Then to check the grant results from `OnRequestPermissionResult`:

```
public boolean checkGrantResults(String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    int granted = 0;

    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length ; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ||
                    permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    granted++;
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // if cancelled
        return false;
    }

    return granted == 2;
}
```

Check location services:

```
public boolean areLocationServicesEnabled(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the method body of `requestBlePermissions()` seems to request for location permissions instead

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the good explanation. Now I feel quite dumb cause I really don't know how to get this working.

Here's my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

And here my activity:

```
public class LightActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;
private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_light);

    if(hasBlePermissions() && areLocationServicesEnabled(this)) {
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth low energy is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
        // displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    }
}

public boolean hasBlePermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void requestBlePermissions(final Activity activity, int requestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, requestCode);
}

public boolean checkGrantResults(String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    int granted = 0;

    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length ; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    granted++;
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // if cancelled
        return false;
    }

    return granted == 2;
}

public boolean areLocationServicesEnabled(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {


        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                         byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("NEW DEVICE", device.getName());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}

I just recognized that hasBlePermissions() always returns false even so the permissions in the manifest are set correctly.

**UPDATE:** Got it working. Once you understand it it's not that hard. First grant the permissions then scan for the device. Here's my updated code in the onCreate method:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
} else {
    if(areLocationServicesEnabled(this)) {
        mHandler = new Handler();

        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me. are u sure this is the code that worked for you?

Comment: see my updated code above. I hope that's the essential part. My code changed quite a bit since my last post so I had the trace it back where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your project with https://github.com/kaviles/BLE_Tutorials
just add this line after you get Adapter in MainActivity:

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently on higher android versions you need to have BOTH of these permissions. I was selectively allowing one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with android BLE sample code from developer site.

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html

Please make sure about UUID and do needful changes to communicate with android application in this sample code if required.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-ble-central, which works well with Android. The Plugin requires the following permissions:

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

BLUETOOTH

BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin, API>=24
I figured out how to make it work, it might not be intuitive that you need COARSE_LOCATION permission to get the Bluetooth to work. Go to the project on Xamarin > right click > Options > Check the boxes for Bluetooth, and location permissions > OK --> rebuild on device

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to app development, but I managed to adapt the BLE GATT example for my Android 8 device. I hope it works for yours as well:

https://github.com/schollp/BluetoothLEGatt-Android8

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10, you also need the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission

Kotlin Code

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                   baseContext,
                   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
               ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
           {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                   this@MainActivity,
                   arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION),
                   12)
           }
```

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? As far as I know only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is required for Android 10.

Comment: This information is wrong... `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is **not** required for BLE in Android 10. `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is enough. This Android Developers [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions) mention only FINE permission, and I have just checked BLE works without BACKGROUND permission.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? As far as I know only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is required for Android 10. Unfortunately it doesn't work,

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with Motorola devices. Motorola devices has location and gps combined into one single option called "location". In other devices ble scanning works when your app has access to location and that's all but if you have Motorola we need also to enable location (gps). It's guite strange and confusing.