# Android BLE discovery issue

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing and Android app with Bluetooth but sometimes I have problems with LE devices discovering: usually the discovery callback return me the the devices found but sometimes, stops working and does not return me the devices.

I tested the code (in debug mode) in different devices (Samsung, LG) and with different Android version (8.0, 6.0, 4.4) but the problem is the same, is not systematic and after some time, it return to works fine.

I have applied all the suggestions found in internet:

- [Android can't find any BLE devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250866/android-cant-find-any-ble-devices)
- [Bluetooth LE Scanning Sometimes Doesn't Find Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041838/bluetooth-le-scanning-sometimes-doesnt-find-devices)
- [Android Bluetooth Low Energy code compatible with API>=21 AND API<21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213951/android-bluetooth-low-energy-code-compatible-with-api-21-and-api21/39597845#39597845)

but the problem persist.

Below a snips of manifest:

```
.
.
.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
.
.
.
```

and bluetooth code:

```
public BLEH_RES StartDiscovery()
{
    .
    .
    .
    CheckPermission();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        return(scanLeDevice21(true));
    else
        return(scanLeDevice18(true));
}

 /**
 * Scan BLE devices on Android API 20 to last version (Android 9.0)
 *
 * @param enable Enable scan
 */
@RequiresApi(21)
private BLEH_RES scanLeDevice21(boolean enable)
{
    bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    if (bluetoothLeScanner == null)
        return(BLEH_RES.BLE_NOT_SUPPORTED);

    if (enable)
    {
        ScanSettings.Builder scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder();
        scanSettings.setScanMode(SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings.build(), BLEScanCallback);
    }
    else
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(BLEScanCallback);

    return(BLEH_RES.OK);
}

/**
 * Scan BLE devices on Android API 18 to 20
 *
 * @param enable Enable scan
 */
private BLEH_RES scanLeDevice18(boolean enable)
{
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null)
        return(BLEH_RES.BT_NOT_SUPPORTED);


    if (enable) 
    {
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    else
    {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }

    return(BLEH_RES.OK);
}

@RequiresApi(21)
private ScanCallback BLEScanCallback = new ScanCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        addDevice(result.getDevice(), result.getRssi(), result.getScanRecord().getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode)
    {
        for(ErrorEvent ee:errorEventList)
            ee.onError(BLEH_EVENT_ERROR.SCAN_FAILED);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int rssi,byte[] scanRecord)
    {
        addDevice(bluetoothDevice, rssi, scanRecord);
    }
};
```

Can you suggest me anything to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by following the suggestions in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267678/7006955

I add to my code all the code suggested and it works fine also in Android 4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that GPS is enabled all the time you searching devices. Also suggest you to watch this about BLE 
https://youtu.be/jDykHjn-4Ng